# Clear memory content in POST

Tags: post, memory-management

I would like to check something about Power-On-Self-Test, How should I enable the Power-On-Self-Test (POST) to clear the memory content?

Comment: There will be nothing in memory at boot. What problem are you having that you believe this would solve?

Comment: I am asked to enable the POST to clear the memory content so I would like to check whether is there such thing or such setting to clear the memory during POST. I don't have much knowledge on POST.

Answer (score 1):

RAM is volatile, so when you remove power everything held is lost. There should be no requirement to purge the RAM content/cache at POST.